# How does Tensorflow ensure thread-safety, for example in QueueRunner?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, thread-safety

Tensorflow's session can be run under multiple threads at the same time.
For example, the `QueueRunner` runs the enqueue operation with several threads simultaneously.

But there is little document talking about thread safety in Tensorflow.

Can anyone give any details about it? For example, how does Tensorflow ensure thread safety when multiple threads run enqueue simultaneously? Thank you very much.